# Adding google-cloud-storage to maven - NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: maven, google-cloud-storage

I am trying to add `google-cloud-storage` to my maven repo and it build/compiles fine but at runtime I keep getting

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/cloud/http/CensusHttpModule
    at com.google.cloud.storage.spi.v1.HttpStorageRpc.<init>(HttpStorageRpc.java:109)
    at com.google.cloud.storage.StorageOptions$DefaultStorageRpcFactory.create(StorageOptions.java:54)
    at com.google.cloud.storage.StorageOptions$DefaultStorageRpcFactory.create(StorageOptions.java:48)
    at com.google.cloud.ServiceOptions.getRpc(ServiceOptions.java:518)
    at com.google.cloud.storage.StorageOptions.getStorageRpcV1(StorageOptions.java:120)
```

This is how my pom file looks like:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.auth</groupId>
    <artifactId>google-auth-library-credentials</artifactId>
    <version>0.20.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>google-cloud-core</artifactId>
    <version>1.84.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>google-cloud-storage</artifactId>
    <version>1.102.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.auth</groupId>
    <artifactId>google-auth-library-oauth2-http</artifactId>
    <version>0.20.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>google-cloud-core-http</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.2</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.api</groupId>
    <artifactId>gax</artifactId>
    <version>1.56.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.api</groupId>
    <artifactId>gax-grpc</artifactId>
    <version>1.56.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
    <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
    <version>29.0-jre</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.protobuf</groupId>
    <artifactId>protobuf-java</artifactId>
    <version>3.11.4</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.protobuf</groupId>
    <artifactId>protobuf-java-util</artifactId>
    <version>3.11.4</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.api.grpc</groupId>
    <artifactId>proto-google-iam-v1</artifactId>
    <version>0.13.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.api-client</groupId>
    <artifactId>google-api-client</artifactId>
    <version>1.30.9</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.api</groupId>
    <artifactId>api-common</artifactId>
    <version>1.9.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.http-client</groupId>
    <artifactId>google-http-client</artifactId>
    <version>1.35.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.http-client</groupId>
    <artifactId>google-http-client-jackson2</artifactId>
    <version>1.35.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.opencensus</groupId>
    <artifactId>opencensus-api</artifactId>
    <version>0.26.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.opencensus</groupId>
    <artifactId>opencensus-contrib-http-util</artifactId>
    <version>0.26.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.grpc</groupId>
    <artifactId>grpc-context</artifactId>
    <version>1.29.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.threeten</groupId>
    <artifactId>threetenbp</artifactId>
    <version>1.4.4</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.apis</groupId>
    <artifactId>google-api-services-storage</artifactId>
    <version>v1-rev171-1.25.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
    <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
    <version>2.8.6</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.api-client</groupId>
    <artifactId>google-api-client-appengine</artifactId>
    <version>1.30.9</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.http-client</groupId>
    <artifactId>google-http-client-appengine</artifactId>
    <version>1.35.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Any idea/tips what I might be missing?

Answer (score 0):

This was a known issue. You can [check it here](https://issuetracker.google.com/76144204).

I suggest that you update to the latest SDK. If that does not fix the issue then try the following:

Copy the com.google.appengine:appengine-api-1.0-sdk from Maven Central and place it in your WEB-INF/lib directory.  Then redeploy as normal.